# AWS Lambda : console.error not overriding

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to override default console statements in Lambda functions, but its not working

```
const logClone = console.log;

console.success = function () {
  const args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.unshift('SUCCESS -');
  return logClone.apply(console, args);
};
const errorClone = console.error;
console.error = function () {
  const args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.unshift('ERROR -');
  return errorClone.apply(console, args);
};



exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.success("I'm in success");
    console.error("I'm in Error");
    callback(null, {statusCode:200,body:'reached'});  // Echo back the first key value    
};
```

Output as below:

```
SUCCESS - I'm in success
I'm in Error
```

Only `SUCCESS` printed, but `ERROR` not working

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Typo: `return logClone.apply` should be `return errorClone.apply` in the second override.

Comment: Yep, its typo in question

Comment: And now I can't reproduce the issue. It just logs: `"SUCCESS - I'm in success"` `"ERROR - I'm in Error"`

Comment: Are you testing in browser or on aws lambda?

Comment: You're mocking/overriding them, not cloning.

Comment: In the browser.

Comment: Try in AWS Lambda Function, screenshot attached

Answer (score 2):

```
const logClone = console.log;
console.success = function () {
  const args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.unshift('SUCCESS -');
  return logClone.apply(console, args);
};

const errorClone = console.error;
console.failure = function () {
  const args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.unshift('ERROR -');
  return errorClone.apply(console, args);
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.success("I'm in success");
    console.failure("I'm in Error");

    console.error('testing')
    callback(null, {statusCode:200,body:'reached'});  // Echo back the first key value    
};
```

using the above code you can add `'ERROR -'` or `'SUCCESS-'` in the line. But in node.js both `console.log` and `console.error` is same visually in a log file. Its just that *console.log* output is sent to *stdout* and *console.error* output is sent to *stderr*. In Browsers, you can see the visual difference between them. I believe, Lambda redirects both stdout and stderr to a file which you can see in cloudwatch.

In Python, however, `logger.error(similar to console.error)` adds an extra `[ERROR]` text, before the timestamp in the beginning of the line which makes it easier to identify the errors.

Comment: By this approach, I need to replace all occurrence of console.error, console.log, console.info in my project.